# How to pass Resultset rs object as parameter to Thread

Tags: java, jdbc

I am new to java threads. My question is:

Can we pass Resultset rs object as parameter to thread.

I searched in google,i got how to pass string,int.But i am not getting how to use object parameter.

My sample program is:

```
public class dataimport
{
    public dataimport()
    {
        connect(); //this function will connect to database and execute query
    }   

    private void connect()
    {
        /* Connect database
        str="SELECT * FROM tablename"; 
        rs1=statement.executeQuery(str);

        while (rs1.next())
        { 
            /* here each record will pass to each thread run() method*/ 
        }   
    }
}
```

Please can any one help me one this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your Object in the constructor on thread creation:

```
public class MyThreadClass implements Runnable {

   public MyThread(Object parameter) {
       // store parameter 
   }

   public void run() {
   //...
   }
}
```